# Set delay in android

Tags: android, for-loop, counter

I want to show 1 to 9 numbers in my app as a counter

```
         TextView te=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

`for(int i=0;i<10;i++ ){
                         try {
                             te.setText("Number"+i);
              Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                         }`

But this doesn't give what i want
How can i do this
Thank you

Comment: **But this doesn't give what i want**. Could please tell what do you want?

Comment: why cant you use a count down timer to acehive this

Comment: I want o show on my screen number count 1 to 10 one after another

Answer (score 10):

**Never ever** put delay on UI thread. Instead, use `Handler` and its `postDelayed` method to perform operations at a regular interval. For example:

```
//define 'int i = 10;' at global level
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        te.setText("Number"+i);
        i--;
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try code similar to this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    protected int _splashTime = 5000;
    private Thread splashTread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                            Home.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            synchronized(splashTread)
            {
                    splashTread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Make the necessary changes to get your thing work perfectly.
This is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If no user interaction was expected when displaying the counter ,what you did should be fine ,just making sure they are running on the UI thread, which could be achieved by putting it in `runOnUiThread` or creating an `Hander` and then `postMessage`.

If user interaction was expected during the counter increasing,you can
create a `Handler` and then call [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountDownTimer directly.
this link might help you
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

you can display the required values in the ontick method